# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-12

I am trying to upgrade my app to Support Android 12 and hence changed compileSDKversion and TargetSdkVersion to 31. Making this change let to the following error message :

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
```

To fix this error I had to upgrade work runtime to

```
"androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"
```

On making this change I get the following error messages:

```
    Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.3
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.3 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.3
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 > com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0 available for offline mode.
```

My Gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

def camerax_version = "1.0.1"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.systems.appname"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 53
    versionName "8.6.5-prd"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.onmicrosoft.myapp.myapp'
    ]
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
}
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha24"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':shared')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.cardiomood.android:android-widgets:0.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:8.0.3"
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.paramsen:noise:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"

    //OAuth
    implementation "net.openid:appauth:0.7.1"
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.4.0'

    //LeakCanary
    //debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'


    //Other features
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.frosquivel:magicaltakephoto:1.0'
    implementation project(path: ':tableview')
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
```

and the other gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    ext.kotlin_native_version = '1.6.10'

    ext {
        dokkaVersion = '0.9.17'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven() { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven() { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        maven() { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependnecies' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokkaVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_native_version"

        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please suggest any changes or steps I can take to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you able to find any solution?

Comment: I had to update my JDK version to 11. Once I did that I updated the path in my project structure. If that does not help please try Invalidate caches/Restart in android studio. Let me know if this helped.